# Can I put elements into zip using for loop instead manually with index number?

Tags: python

```
data = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
result = zip(data[0], data[1], data[2])
```

Can I put elements into zip using for loop instead manually with index number?

Comment: You don't need loop or index you can just use in-place unpacking. `zip(*data)`

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted, although it was a duplicate it was a perfectly understandable question in itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman It seems like people just downvote duplicate questions now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `*` to expand the list as arguments:

```
result = zip(*data)
```